# Assigning keys and storing in a dictionary Python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, random

For an event of rolling a six-sided die. I need to randomly simulate the event 1000 times and plot a histogram of results for each number on the dice. I want to assign the results for each number to a key of the same value (1 for number of 1s{1:164...}).

I need help assigning keys and storing everyting in a dictionary

```
import random
test_data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #this will keep track of the results
n = 1000 # number of simulations
 
 
for i in range(n):
  result = random.randint(1, 6)
  test_data[result - 1] = test_data[result - 1] + 1
 
for i in range(len(test_data)):
  print ("Number of ", i+1, "'s: ", test_data[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic = dict()
for i in range(len(test_data)):
    dic[i+1] = test_data[i]
```

Comment: you are reassigning the value not incrementing

Comment: I'm using `range(len(test_data))` which is 6, `i` value changes each iteration.

Comment: if you want to create dictionary from list then why using for loop `dict(zip(range(1, 7), test_data))`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a dictionary with keys 1-6, and then increase the value for each key. Details can be found in [Python documentation for Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

To  declare a dictionary with keys 1-6, you can create a dictionary with hard coded key and value pair like:

```
test_data = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
```

Or you can use (Thanks to @deadshot) :

```
test_data = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 7), 0)
```

Code:

```
import random


test_data = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 7), 0)
#test_data = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}

n = 1000 # number of simulations

for i in range(n):
  result = random.randint(1, 6)
  test_data[result] = test_data[result] + 1
 
for i in test_data:
  print ("Number of "+str(i)+"'s: "+str(test_data[i]))
```

Output:

```
Number of 1's: 178
Number of 2's: 172
Number of 3's: 150
Number of 4's: 166
Number of 5's: 160
Number of 6's: 174
```

**References:**

- [Python documentation for Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: for dictionary creation you can do it this way `dict.fromkeys(range(1, 7), 0)`